# How can I create a formatted text file from a series of selections from a Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, text-formatting

I have a Java Swing application that has various screens / tabs from 1 to 8. There are series of selections and Text Inputs in each tab and in the final tab, I have a button to create a text file based on the selections the user has done. The text file should be formed in a formatted manner and that will be defined in the code. I would like to understand if there is a way to do this, other than defining each selection / control in the application to a corresponding text segment using `FileWriter` or anything similar.

Example:

In Screen 1:

```
User Selects "Radio 1" and Enters Text "Godzilla"
```

When in the button click, I need to create a text file suitably in this format.

```
Screen 1 {
Best Movie : Godzilla
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: *"The text file should be formed in a formatted manner and that will be defined in the code. I would like to understand if there is a way to do this, other than defining each selection / control in the application to a corresponding text segment using FileWriter or anything similar."*  There are lots of ways to do it.  As to serializing it in a structured format, I recommend [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) with Java beans that store the values of interest.

Comment: Why *"..other than.."*?

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Hello and thanks for your response. Frankly this is a 10 tabbed application with lot of information inside each tab. The application is like a dominos, each selection in a tab invokes / shows corresponding options in succeeding tabs. Having said that, I wanted to know if there is a less complex way of converting these selections to a formatted text file. Or a good approach to implement this. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Query the relevant component models in your implementation of `java.awt.print.Printable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks exactly like JSON! Check it out here: http://www.json.org/java/

It is formatted exactly the same way your example is! :)